# Python writing a pdf file after reading a pgp encrypted file results in a corrupted file

Tags: python, file, encryption

I'm trying to read a pgp encrypted file using a key stored in a file and writing decrypted message to a local system using pgpy. It ends up in a corrupted format. Here is my code, any one know what might be causing it?

```
from pgpy import PGPKey, PGPMessage

privateKey, _ = PGPKey.from_file(str("/Users/shashank/devroot/home/keys/0/pvt.txt"))

ENC_FILE = '/Users/shashank/devroot/sachin.pdf_enfos.zip.pgp'
encrypted_message = PGPMessage.from_file(ENC_FILE)
with privateKey.unlock('passphrase'):
    decrypted_message = privateKey.decrypt(encrypted_message)
    message = decrypted_message.message
    f = open("/Users/shashank/Downloads/test.pdf", "wb")
    f.write(message)
    f.close()
```

the resulting test.pdf ends up corrupted.

Comment: How do you know the unencrypted file is a PDF?

Comment: the format doesn't change after decrypting it, the encrypted file was a pdf

Comment: Not sure if i'm reading your code correctly. but if you've decrypted the message would it not be plainText and not a bytes-like object. so when writing it to a new file you would just use 'w' not 'wb'

Comment: @KJ you're right that's what I'm doing I forgot to unzip after decrypting it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help, I had zipped the file then encrypted it but after decrypting it I forgot to unzip.